# Filling exterior of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to create a picture like the one attached below using `tikzpicture`. I could only draw two concentric circles. How do I colour them as in the picture?

Can anyone help me? I am pretty new to usage of Ti*k*Z.

[image: wanted]

Comment: Can you edit your post to include what you've gotten so far?

Comment: `\filldraw[blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);` does not work? I assume, you mean `fill`, not shading

Comment: Welcome! Please always include a minimal document we can compile to reproduce the situation. Very frustrating when somebody says 'I can only draw ... - I can't add the last arrow' and then fails to include any code, so that anybody who wants to help has to draw all of the `...` before they can even see what the problem is with the last arrow, which they might not be able to help with anyway. ;)

Comment: @cfr: I'll keep this in mind. Yeah, I should have added a document showing what I've done so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
 \psset{fillstyle = solid}
  \psframe[fillcolor = orange](0,0)(4,3)
  \pscircle(2,1.5){1}
  \pscircle[fillcolor = cyan](2,1.5){0.8}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

In case you want the fill color of the ring to be the same as the background color, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\def\bgcolor{green!50} % background color
\pagecolor{\bgcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
 \psset{fillstyle = solid}
  \psframe[fillcolor = orange](0,0)(4,3)
  \pscircle[fillcolor = \bgcolor](2,1.5){1}
  \pscircle[fillcolor = cyan](2,1.5){0.8}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: Does this fill the outer ring with white or avoid filling it? I'm not sure which is wanted - just curious.

Comment: @cfr It fills with white. (See updated answer for a workaround.)

Comment: Thanks! I can't upvote again, though ....

Answer (score 7):

Here is a suggestion using the `even odd rule` to fill the orange area, i.e. the rectangle without the outer circle.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill=orange,even odd rule]
    (-4, -4) rectangle (4,4)
    (0,0)circle[radius=2]
  ;
  \path[fill=blue] 
    (0,0) circle [radius=1.5]
  ;
  \path[draw,very thick]
    (0,0) foreach \r in {1.5,2}{circle [radius=\r]}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think a reverse clip is a cleaner solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz

Comment: for more complicated paths that is :)

Comment: This seems the simplest solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easiest to do this by shading the whole picture, and then drawing a white circle and a blue one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % fills entire rectangle
    \fill[orange] (-4, -4) rectangle (4,4);
    % removes filling inside circle
    \filldraw[fill=white, draw=black, very thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    % adds blue circle
    \filldraw[fill=blue, draw=black, very thick] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really 'remove filling'. It just fills over it with white. If the page is coloured, you'll see the white and not the background colour.